# Running pycharm project as standalone project

Tags: python, pycharm

Hi guys i managed to complete a python project for work in pycharm.

It has 3 python script files and a few additional imported modules/dependecies.

How do i export the project and run it on another pc via terminal by running the mainprogram.py file

e.g python mainprogram.py

Comment: does the other pc have all the dependencies installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a requirement.txt file which contains all the modules used in your project so if you are using virtualenv you can simply do

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Otherwise you need to do manually so that it will look like

```
decorator==4.3.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
entrypoints==0.2.3
Flask==1.0.2
google==2.0.1
```

It's just for example.
So after you move to the different system you can do

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to install all the modules & at the end simply run the file with

```
python mainprogram.py
```

Comment: Hi thank you this worked ! I have a question do i need to copy the whole pycharm directory to another pc for this to work ?
can i just copy the script files and requirements.txt?

Comment: just copy all the files to a new folder & point your terminal directory to that folder. After that, you can run the scripts.